# Adding errorbars in barchart in lattice when there are 2 groups

Tags: r, bar-chart, lattice

I know it is much easier by using ggplot2, but I need to get it done by lattice.

Here is my example:

```
data <- structure(c(0.67, 0.67, 0.76, 0.66, 0.71, 0.6, 0.52, 0.6, 0.71, 0.76, 
0.76, 0.71, 0.6, 0.61, 0.9, 0.5, 0.58, 0.84, 0.68, 0.88,
0.89, 0.96, 1, 0.95, 1, 1, 0.98, 0.78, 0.98, 1, 
1, 0.99, 1, 1, 0.95, 0.92, 1, 0.91, 1, 0.87, 
0.91, 0.72, 0.73, 0.55, 0.82, 0.87, 0.64, 0.75, 0.75, 1, 
0.81, 0.79, 1, 0.74, 0.57, 0.84, 1, 0.95, 0.78, 0.95), .Dim = c(20L, 3L), 
.Dimnames =     list(
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"), c("A", 
"B", "C")))

means <- apply(data, 2, mean)

errors <- apply(data, 2, sd)

plot.data <- data.frame(colnames(data), means, errors)

colnames(plot.data) <- c("var", "mean", "error")

plot.data<-cbind(rbind(plot.data,plot.data),p=c(rep('n',3),rep('m',3)))
plot.data<-cbind(rbind(plot.data,plot.data),mb=c(rep('j',6),rep('k',6)))
```

to plot

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
prepanel.ci <- function(x, y, lx, ux, subscripts,...) {
x <- as.numeric(x)
lx <- as.numeric(lx[subscripts])
ux <- as.numeric(ux[subscripts])
list(ylim = range(0, x, ux, lx, finite = TRUE))
}


panel.ci <- function(x, y, lx, ux, subscripts,...) {
x <- as.numeric(x)
y <- as.numeric(y)
lx <- as.numeric(lx[subscripts])
ux <- as.numeric(ux[subscripts])
panel.barchart(x, y, ...)
panel.arrows( x, lx, x, ux, col = 'black',
             length = 0.25, unit = "native",
             angle=90 ,code = 2)
}

p <- useOuterStrips(barchart(mean~var|p+mb, data=plot.data,stack=F,
          lx=plot.data$mean,
          ux=plot.data$mean+plot.data$error,
          panel=panel.ci,
          prepanel=prepanel.ci))
print(p)
```

then I could correctly add the errorbars, as shown in the figure1
[image]

When I add a group factor, `g`.

```
plot.data<-cbind(rbind(plot.data,plot.data),g=c(rep('aa',12),rep('tt',12)))

p<-useOuterStrips(barchart(mean~var|p+mb, group=g, plot.data))

print(p)
```

[image]

Now I add the error bar, it goes wrong:

```
p <- useOuterStrips(barchart(mean~var|p+mb, group=g, data=plot.data,stack=F,
          lx=plot.data$mean,
          ux=plot.data$mean+plot.data$error,
          panel=panel.ci,
          prepanel=prepanel.ci))
print(p)
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: solved. 

see this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383623/adding-error-bars-to-a-barchart-with-multiple-groups

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `ggplot2`:

```
dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.9)
p <- ggplot(data=plot.data, aes(y=mean, x=var, fill=g)) +
  geom_bar(position=dodge, stat="identity") + facet_grid(mb ~ p)
p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-error, ymax=mean+error), position=dodge, width=0.25)
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i need to get the result by lattice.